# Error while installing Tortoise TTS using the Conda (CPU only PyTorch install)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, anaconda, text-to-speech

I've been trying to install Tortoise TTS on my local computer with AMD Integrated Graphics so from the site as I don't have NVIDIA GPU I can't install the CUDA version, also can't use the ROCm version as the site says its not supported on Windows for some reason. So I went with the CPU only install for PyTorch.

I have installed the required files from the github repo - https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts
and have followed the steps from the installation tutorial using Conda (miniconda) and have installed from the requirements.txt file and the setup.py file.

But on running the following command I get an error -

```
(tortoise) C:\Users\KIIT\tortoise-tts-main>python tortoise/do_tts.py --text "I'm going to speak this" --voice random --preset fast
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tortoise/do_tts.py", line 7, in <module>
    from api import TextToSpeech, MODELS_DIR
  File "C:\Users\KIIT\tortoise-tts-main\tortoise\api.py", line 9, in <module>
    import progressbar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'progressbar'
```

I can't seem to figure out which part of the installation went wrong. If anyone knows how to solve this and install Tortoise, please do help me out.

I've tried to quite a few tutorials I could find to install Tortoise but I keep running into errors and dependency issues so I took the conda way. I expected for the above command to generate the output WAV file as the demo says but there seems to be some modules missing which I can't figure out why as I followed all the instructions as they were.

Comment: Does `pip freeze -l` show `progressbar`? I'd guess it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the requirements of the project [here](https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts/blob/main/requirements.txt)

for example progresbar package

> pip install -r requirements.txt

and check venv which python you're using - may be it's not that one where you've installed requirements